# Как организовать вывод архива определенной категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый, у меня имеется несколько рубрик, категорий, в шаблон archive.php выводится все скопом, мне это не очень нравиться, у меня есть рубрика тренинги которая выводится на отдельный шаблон, чуть выше я разместил функцию `<?php wp_get_archives( array('type' => 'yearly') ); ?>`
она выводит ссылки по годам, когда я перехожу по этим ссылкам то попадаю на все архивы, а хотел бы попасть именно на архив данной рубрики, те кликнул и погрузился шаблон со всеми постами за год с данной категории, как то так. Как сделать не знаю. Возможно есть какие то мысли по этому поводу буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблон `archive.php` используется, когда не найден более приоритетный шаблон.
В вашем случае, можно сделать шаблон `category-trainings.php`, который будет выбирать посты только из категории trainings.

[Иерархия шаблонов WP](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

Comment: Именно я так и организовал вывод постов с определенной категории в шаблон category-name.php но при клике на архив я попадаю на страницу archive.php где все архивы скопом

Comment: @AntonEssential что написано в шаблоне? 

>> при клике на архив <<

при клике куда? где формируется ссылка на архив?